# Blank(white) textfields in iReport 4.6.0

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I began using iReport for creating JasperReports since version 4.5.1 and then I started using 4.6.0 and created a couple of reports with it. **The problem is that whenever I open the "old reports" (generated in 4.5.1) the textfields' fonts appear white coloured (it becomes "invisible" to me).** When I double-click it, it shows the text, but it's terrible for edition because I can't see how the text is being displayed on the page.

It works fine with documents created by 4.6.0 and opened by 4.6.0, but not with documents created by previous versions. I guess it has to do with its xml (an attribute maybe).

Things I tried:
(1) Select another colour [green] for the font. (2) Open the .jasper compiled file and generate a new .jrxml.

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: I have the same editions (4.5.1 and 4.6.0) and it is everything ok for me. What OS are you using? Did you import the old settings (from previous version) during the first iReport start?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 (with iReport 4.6.0) and the "old report" I'm trying to edit was created on Windows (with iReport 4.5.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I found out what was causing the "bug". It happens that the first report I created in iReport 4.5.1 was saved on Windows with Arial font (which doesn't exist in Ubuntu/Linux). So I deleted the "fontName" tags on the JRXML file.

Answer (score 0):

Some fonts are not available on linux and if your report template use them, you will have the described problem. If you want to still use the Arial or some other non-linux fonts, you can try to install this package and retry:

> sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts